# Statically linking a library in Android Studio 3.x and CMake

Tags: android, gradle, cmake, android-ndk, android-studio-3.0

First of all, this is my error.

```
Build command failed.
Error while executing process /Users/{user}/Library/Android/sdk/cmake/3.6.4111459/bin/cmake with arguments {--build /Users/{user}/Desktop/android/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/arm64-v8a --target native-lib}
ninja: error: 'src/main/jniLibs/zlib/arm64-v8a/lib/libz.a', needed by '../../../../build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/arm64-v8a/libnative-lib.so', missing and no known rule to make it
```

I have a statically linked prebuilt zlib.a library for every ARCHs (armeabi, armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86, x86_64) and placed the library like this.

```
app/src/main/jniLibs/zlib/${ANDROID_ABI}/include/zlib.h
app/src/main/jniLibs/zlib/${ANDROID_ABI}/lib/libz.a
```

Here is my CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

add_library(native-lib SHARED src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp)

add_library(libz STATIC IMPORTED)

set_target_properties(libz PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION src/main/jniLibs/zlib/${ANDROID_ABI}/lib/libz.a)

include_directories(src/main/jniLibs/zlib/${ANDROID_ABI}/include)

find_library(log-lib log)

target_link_libraries(native-lib libz ${log-lib})
```

in a Java file,

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("libz");
    System.loadLibrary("native-lib");
}
```

I don't have no idea about this issue. It seems okay. I don't touch build.gradle, should I? What am I missing? What is problem?

Answer (score 2):

Property *IMPORTED_LOCATION* should be an **absolute path**.

Use `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}` for refer to the directory with currently processed `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
set_target_properties(libz PROPERTIES
  IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/jniLibs/zlib/${ANDROID_ABI}/lib/libz.a)
```